# Value cannot be null. Parameter name: fileOrServerOrConnection

Tags: web-part, sharepoint-addin, project-server

I have a web part for Project Server 2013 that was developed by a colleague that's no longer in the company, and I need to support it. When I try to add the web part to a page I get the following error:

[image: error from SharePoint]

Deploying it from Visual Studio is successful because I can see the web part added using Get-SPSolution in the Powershell, but no errors show in the VS output window, and there was nothing in the Event Viewer.

I searched the entire code for the string "fileOrServerOrConnection", but I found nothing.

I have to admit I'm completely at a loss here because I have no idea how to investigate this problem.

Any suggestions at all? I don't expect a full answer to the problem, but at least some help on how to proceed the investigation would be very much appreciatted.

Comment: try to look for DataContext instead https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb350721(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so the problem was coming from [ConfigurationManager](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager(v=vs.110).aspx). Apparently, ConfigurationManager, scans the SharePoint's web.config file, to get a connection string, and then pass it onto [DataContext](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb350721(v=vs.110).aspx). But because this key with the connection string didn't exist, the value being passed to DataContext was null.

Hope this helps someone out there.